# Alternative for HTML5 input type="week"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an alternative to achieve the **html5 input type="week"?**

[image]

Comment: Some JS/jQ datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like a polyfill?  [Here's one](https://github.com/jonstipe/week-polyfill).